# MMA has an error in calculating the minimum polynomial of a rational number

Tags: bugs, polynomials

The minimum polynomial of `Power[2, (3)^-1] (-(1/2) + (I Sqrt[3])/2)` Python minimal_polynomial function can get the result as `x^2 + 2^(1/3)*x + 2^(2/3)`
.(In Python ** means^)
[image: Python]

```py
import os
import sympy as sy
from sympy import minimal_polynomial, sqrt, solve, QQ, Rational
#Rational

from sympy.abc import x, y, z
s = minimal_polynomial (2 ** Rational (1, 
     3)*(Rational (-1, 2) + 
      Rational (1, 2)*3 ** Rational (1, 2)*sqrt (-1)), x, 
   domain = QQ.algebraic_field (2 ** Rational (1, 3)))
print (s)
print (sy.latex (s))
```

But MMA can't get the result.

```
MinimalPolynomial[Power[2, (3)^-1] (-(1/2) + (I Sqrt[3])/2), x, 
 Extension -> Power[2, (3)^-1]]
```

Comment: This problem may be a bug of MMA.

Comment: I guess this is a fix: `s0 = Power[2, (3)^-1] (-(1/2) + (I Sqrt[3])/2);
a0 = Power[2, (3)^-1];
mpq = MinimalPolynomial[s0, x, 
   Extension -> ToNumberField[{s0, a0}][[1, 1]]];
mpcandidates = FactorList[mpq, Extension -> a0];
Select[mpcandidates[[All, 1]], Simplify[# == 0 /. x -> s0] &]`

Comment: This method is too complex. MMA should redefine and encapsulate this function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `MinimalPolynomial[s, x, Extension -> a]` gives the characteristic polynomial of the algebraic number $s$ over the field $Q[a]$.

https://planetmath.org/characteristicpolynomialofalgebraicnumber

`MinimalPolynomial[s, x, Extension ->a ]` is equal to `MinimalPolynomial[s, x]^d`, where $d$ is the extension degree of $Q[a]$ over $Q[s]$. This requires that $s$ belong to $Q[a]$.

Unfortunately, the documentation page of `MinimalPolynomial` says differently. The following tutorial gives a correct specification:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AlgebraicNumberFields.html