# How to check if a complex number belongs to a quadratic field

Tags: list-manipulation, complex

I am working with lists of complex numbers and want to be able to determine which out of these lists contains only elements from a certain quadratic field, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt D) = \{ a+b\sqrt D :a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Here, $D$ is an integer, positive or negative.

**What I want:** I am trying to write a function `checkQ[D_,z_]` which returns `True` if a complex number `z` belongs to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ and `False` otherwise.

I have a piecemeal function written currently to do this, but it (a) sometimes fails, and (b) is slow. Unfortunately, I am working with quite large lists, so it does me no good to have a slow function to check this (or a function that doesn't always work, for that matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method:

```
ToNumberField[Sqrt[2], ToNumberField[{Sqrt[2], I}, All][[1, 1]]]
ToNumberField[Sqrt[3], ToNumberField[{Sqrt[2], I}, All][[1, 1]]]
ToNumberField[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] I, 
 ToNumberField[{Sqrt[2], I}, All][[1, 1]]]
```

The above codes determine in turn whether $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} I$ are in the double quadratic extension domain $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2,I) $.

Or use the following Python code to make some judgments:

```python
import os
import sympy as sy
from sympy import minimal_polynomial,sqrt,solve,QQ,Rational,poly
#Floating point numbers are best represented in rational

from sympy.abc import x,y,z
x1=sqrt(2)
x2=sqrt(3)
x3=sqrt(2)+sqrt(3)
x4=2**Rational(1,3)*(Rational(-1,2)+Rational(1,2)*3**Rational(1,2)*sqrt(-1))

s=minimal_polynomial(x3,x,domain=QQ.algebraic_field(x1,x2))
print(s)
print(sy.latex(s))
s2=minimal_polynomial(x2,x,domain=QQ.algebraic_field(x1,x4))
print(s2)
```

[image]

*The above method may not be able to deal with complex algebraic numbers.*

We can also use the function `MinimalPolynomial` of MMA to make relevant judgment, but [there may be bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213170/mma-has-an-error-in-calculating-the-minimum-polynomial-of-a-rational-number) in function `MinimalPolynomial` that have not been fixed:

```
F = ToNumberField[{Sqrt[3], I}, All][[1, 1]]
MinimalPolynomial[Sqrt[3] + 2 I, x, Extension -> F]
MinimalPolynomial[Sqrt[2] + 2 I, x, Extension -> F]
```

Comment: I had not known that was a function. This is perfect, thank you.